# WebMatrix filling attribute and JavaScript Reading Attribute not producing expected results

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, razor, webmatrix

I am having an issue with the following code:

SECTION FROM CSHTML FILE:

```
                        @if(errorMessage != "")
                        {
                            err="err";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            err="";
                        }
                        @if(errorMessage == "")
                        {
                            foreach(var row in db.Query(stringCompiler, EntryID, POIName, DateLastModified, Gender, Race, Height, Weight, HairColor, EyeColor, DOB, Age, SS, DL, DOC, VehicleTag, FBI, Officer, HomePhone, CellPhone, CellPhone2, CellPhone3, POICautions, WorkPhone, WeightedAggregate, Address, AdditionalDescriptors, Aliases, SourceOfInformation, AddressInformation, KnownAssociates, VehicleDescription, Comments, SummarizedIncidents, AllCellPhones, AllPhones, betDOB1, betDOB2, betDLM1, betDLM2, betAge1, betAge2, POILastName, SearchAll))
                            {
                                <div class="searchResult">
                                    <table style="background-color: #beebeb;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">ENTRY ID</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">FIRST NAME</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">LAST NAME</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">DATE LAST MODIFIED</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">DOB</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">AGE</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">ADDRESS</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">VEHICLE TAG#</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">OFFICER</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">HOME PHONE</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">CELL PHONE</td>
                                            <td class="entryLabel">WEIGHTED AGGREGATE</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.EntryID</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.POIName</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.POILastName</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.DateLastModified</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.DOB</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.Age</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.Address</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.VehicleTag</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.Officer</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.HomePhone</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.CellPhone</td>
                                            <td class="entry">@row.WeightedAggregate</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="13" style="text-align: center;"><form method="post" action="/ComputeLookupToVAndE.cshtml"><input type="hidden"  name="veEntryID" hidden="hidden" readonly="true" value="@row.EntryID" /><br/><input type="submit" value="View & Edit" class="btn3" style="height: 40px; width: 100px;" /><br/><br/></form></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div><br/>
                                ResultCount += 1;
                            }
                            <input type="hidden" id="ResultCount" value="@ResultCount" />
                            <input id="err" type="hidden" value='@err' />
                        }
```

SECTION FROM JAVASCRIPT FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($("#err").val() == "err")
{
    $("#searchForm").attr('action', "/LookUpEntry.cshtml#top");
}
else
{
    $("#searchForm").attr('action', "/LookUpEntry.cshtml#searchList");
}
});
```

Obviously I am trying to change the value of the hidden input element to "err" before the page is rendered by C# if any error messages have been stored in the variable errorMessage.

Once done JavaScript is supposed to read this value and then if it is "err" change the action attribute of the form to append "#top" (for named anchor, so the loaded position on the page changes based off of whether there is an error message or results to view), otherwise the form's action attribute should be changed (still by JavaScript) to append #searchList).

Any idea why JavaScript and C# won't play well together?  The errors I am getting are haphazard (like it won't work the first time, then doesn't work at all), anyway based on the code below, it still never goes to (#top), although when trying a few things before this exact coding (I don't remember exactly what they were) it would sometimes (although never the first time) go to the top if it had errored.

Why is jQuery not doing its job?  It seems like this should just work to me...

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help

Comment: javascript and C# don't really interact, so there's not a problem concerning them being together.  Perhaps if you navigate to the page, then view source, and look at the raw HTML, you'll see how err is being set.  That could shed some light on what's actually going on.  I'm sure that err is being set before the page loads into the browser and before the javascript runs.

Comment: @Knox, yeah, I know, they affect it at different times, C# affects it before JavaScript even looks at it, and by the time JavaScript sees it, it has already been rendered by C#.  I didn't mean literally, I just meant that anytime i try to place a dynamic value with C# and pick it up on the client side, JavaScript always acts like an inebriated moose, and screws it all up.

Comment: @Knox
Your suggestion to check the raw HTML helped me better visualize what was wrong.  I wouldn't have understood what was going wrong (at least not this soon) without your help.  Thanks again, Knox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I have it figured out and I suppose it does make sense:

It does change the value as it should, but the action (how the form [or rather where, the way I look at it] handles the data posted) is already set to what it where it will go regardless of the results of the current search.  In short: It is a step behind. When I click to search and an error Message is produced, it will rewrite the action as intended, but it will, of course, only come into effect on the next search not the current one as that was already determined on the previous submit.

What's wrong with my code?  Nothing syntactically, the methodology (logic) is in err.